# Rotate object in python in BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine

Here's my code:

```
import bge
from bge import logic
from math import degrees

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
own_rotation = own.worldOrientation.to_euler()
mimic = own.parent
mimic_rotation = mimic.worldOrientation.to_euler()

own_rotation_x = "%.0f" % degrees(own_rotation.x)
own_rotation_y = "%.0f" % degrees(own_rotation.y)
own_rotation_z = "%.0f" % degrees(own_rotation.z)

mimic_rotation_x = "%.0f" % degrees(mimic_rotation.x)
mimic_rotation_y = "%.0f" % degrees(mimic_rotation.y)
mimic_rotation_z = "%.0f" % degrees(mimic_rotation.z)

def mimic_process():
    if own_rotation_x > mimic_rotation_x:
        then own.worldOrientation.to_euler.x -1
    elif own_rotation_x < mimic_rotation_x:
        then own.worldOrientation.to_euler.x +1
```

I am fairly new to python. I am trying to get an object to, every single 2 GE ticks (didn't specify that in script yet), an object add/subtract/do nothing to its rotation to try to match another object (in this case, parent). I get an error the line following the function. I am trying to fix my current code I have for the function, but I don't quite understand how to directly add/subtract/do nothing to an object's rotation based off what I have so far. How can I rotate this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: `to_euler` is a function. You need to add brackets to the expression to call the result and not the function itself: `own.worldOrientation.to_euler().x` check the blender console for details on script errors.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `then` inside of the if statements and replacing the `-` and `+` with `-=` and `+=`:

```
def mimic_process():
    if own_rotation_x > mimic_rotation_x:
        own.worldOrientation.to_euler.x -= 1
    elif own_rotation_x < mimic_rotation_x:
        own.worldOrientation.to_euler.x += 1
```

Comment: My object isn't rotating; although, own.applyRotation ((0, 0, 0), True) works.